# Android Service, Thread and WakeLock

Tags: android

I have a backgroud service that acquires a "partial wake lock" and starts an handler thread. I know that, for some reasons, Android can kill this service and restart it again. My question is, what happens to my thread? will it be stopped calling some methods, brutally destroyed or does it continue the execution normally?
Regarding the wake lock, will it somehow be released by the system or not?

Answer (score 1):

> Will it be stopped calling some methods, brutally destroyed or does it continue the execution normally?

According to my experiment on small RAM of the Android device, the `Service` can be killed by Android system on high memory pressure. Android system doesn't trigger your `Service` to call `onDestroy` method. I think, the system pauses the `Service`'s thread. Even if the `Service` return `START_STICKY` or `START_REDELIVER_INTENT`, but they don't guarantee that your `Service` will be started again.

> Regarding the wake lock, will it somehow be released by the system or not?

Android system doesn't guarantee to releases the wakelock, unless you call [`startWakefulService(context, service)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/WakefulBroadcastReceiver.html). It uses wakelock as long as your `Service` is running.